# Linq to Sql: Detaching/re-attaching entities for sending across the wire

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, serialization, n-tier-architecture

I'm using L2S in an N-Tier environment and am running an issue when trying to send associated entities across the wire. I apologize in advance for the lengthy question but it's a very specific situation.

Basically I am loading a table, call it Items, and another table, call it ItemMappings. Items and ItemsMappings are related in a one to many relationship. So each ItemMapping has an ItemId property. In L2S I'm getting a collection of ItemMappings in the Item class, and an Item reference in the ItemMappings class, which is great.

However, because of the N-Tier environment, I've designed some wrapper classes that encapsulate change-tracking on the client-side so it can be retrieved when returned to the server for saving. This works by tracking changes for each entity type. Which means that I have one tracking set for Items (TrackingSet

So this means that across the wire I am sending the Items and ItemMappings separately (actually they are sent together in a container, but as far as serialization goes they are separate). Now if I do not intervene in the serialization process, what actually goes across the wire for the items collection is something like the following pseudo-XML:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <itemId>1</itemId>
    <itemMappings> 
      <itemMapping>
        <itemId>1</itemId>
      </itemMapping>
    </itemMappings>
  </item>
  <item>
    <itemId>2</itemId>
    <itemMappings> 
      <itemMapping>
        <itemId>2</itemId>
      </itemMapping>
    </itemMappings>
  </item>
</items>
```

What I'm trying to show with that is that the serialized items collection includes the item-mappings associated to the items. But because the item-mappings are actually being sent as well, in fact I end up sending the item-mappings collection twice: Once on its own, and once embedded in the items collection. This means that my wire-footprint is unnecessarily large.

What I want to do is dissociate the entities in an OnSerializing method in my container class, leaving only the item IDs on the itemMapping objects, and then in an OnDeserialized method, re-associate them based on these IDs.

Unfortunately, in the OnSerializing method, if I set the ItemMapping.Item property to null, and then try to set the ItemID property to the ID of the Item that I just set to null, I get the infamous ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException. Just a bit infuriating it is :)

If you've gotten this far with my question, I already owe you thanks. If you understand my issue and have any suggestions, I shall be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an instance's properties during serialization is surely a recipe for trouble!

I recommend having some classes for querying the database, and other classes for wire representations.  This decouples your database from your service contract.

```
public class ServiceResponse
{
  public List<Item> TheItems {get;set;}
  public List<ItemMapping> TheMappings {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
  public int ItemId {get;set;}
  // TODO more properties, but no ItemMappings property
}

public class ItemMapping
{
  public int ItemId {get;set;}
  // TODO more properties
}
```

Comment: As it's been almost a year since the post, I'm afraid the issue is no longer relevant for me. I hope others can benefit from your answer, though. Thanks!